# Change Subversion creds in Eclipse / Pydev

Tags: eclipse, svn, ide

In Eclipse + PyDev + Subclipse, how can I change the user who is accessing the subversion repository without having to re-checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to SVN repository exploring perspective(eclipse) (Window->Open perspective->SVN Repository Exploring)
2. right click on the correct 'Repository Location'
3. Select 'Location properties'
4. Update your authentication information

Comment: Very close - I had to click "relocate."  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can remove the saved authentication - credentials...

1. unix-based systems this is in `~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple`. On windows in `c:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Application Data\subversion\auth\svn.simple`.
2. if subclipse is configured to use the JavaSVN adapter --> the .keyring file mentioned in the post appears to be located in the eclipse directory (not the workspace, the actually directory where the eclipse executable is found) under configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.keyring. This is a binary file and hence must be deleted.